# How to use ChartjsPluginStacked100 javascript only, no typescript

Tags: javascript, chart.js

good day. Im trying to use the plugin [chartjs-plugin-stacked100](https://github.com/y-takey/chartjs-plugin-stacked100) with chart.js vs3 but im not having any luck. it stays as normal stacked horizontal bar chart.

I think im doing something wrong when importing or registering i but not know what im doing wrong.

here is how im doing my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-stacked100@1.0.0"></script>


</head>
<body>


  
    <div id="my-chart-container" style="height:400px;">
        <canvas id="my-chart" ></canvas>
      </div>

    <script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

and here is how im doing my js:

```
Chart.register(ChartjsPluginStacked100);
new Chart(document.getElementById("my-chart"), {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["2010-2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"],
      datasets: [
        { label: "IG", data: [0, 250, 7417.5, 650, 1455], backgroundColor: "rgba(244, 143, 177, 0.6)" },
        { label: "HY", data: [0, 0, 0, 1000, 0], backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.6)" },
        { label: "NR", data: [0, 675, 4182.5, 1505, 1735], backgroundColor: "rgba(100, 181, 246, 0.6)" }
      ]
  },
  options: {
     indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
            xAxis:{
                stacked:true
            },
            yAxis:{
                stacked:true
            },
        },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
          const datasetIndex = tooltipItem.datasetIndex;
          const datasetLabel = data.datasets[datasetIndex].label;
          // You can use two type values.
          // `data.originalData` is raw values,
          // `data.calculatedData` is percentage values, e.g. 20.5 (The total value is 100.0)
          const originalValue = data.originalData[datasetIndex][tooltipItem.index];
          const rateValue = data.calculatedData[datasetIndex][tooltipItem.index];
          return `${datasetLabel}: ${rateValue}% (raw ${originalValue})`;
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      plugins:[ChartDataLabels],
      stacked100: { enable: true, replaceTooltipLabel: false }
    }
  }
});
```

if anyone can guide me to do it correctly would be appreciated.

here is a jsbin with it, [example](https://jsbin.com/xaqewubequ/edit?html,js,output)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: i didn't understand what you exactly wanted. could you tell me clearly please

Comment: Sorry if made a bad explanation .. for some reason seems like the plugin is not being  called / loaded, and i think im doing things wrong:  it says that it needs to be registered via Chart.register(plugin name) or via the options, so im doing something the wrong way because is like is doing nothing.

the chart bar should use all the x space, and its like a normal stacked bar now.

Comment: Highly doubt it has anything to do with it but at least your tooltip section is wrong, its in the wrong namespace: [`tooltips namespace was renamed to tooltip to match the plugin name
legend, title and tooltip namespaces were moved from options to options.plugins`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html#specific-changes)

Comment: not related to it. i think they way to call the plugin is not right and is doing nothing.